# How to resolve merge conflicts in multiple commits in EGit?

Tags: eclipse, git, merge, egit

I have multiple commits (30+) on the same branch that are in conflict with another branch. The conflicts are reported during rebase.
I can resolve those conflicts once (in one commit), but repeating it 30 times does not make sense to me.

Any recommendations on how to do this in Eclipse (EGit)? For example, would you recommend using "Skip commit" button?

Comment: If the multiple commits are on multiple branches you can do the change once and then cherry pick the commit with the change on all other branches. If the multiple commits are on the same branch, I do not understand why you have to repeat it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try using merge instead of rebase.
2. If you have to use rebase, try using git rerere command.

Details:
[Git rebase conflicts after successful merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225706/git-rebase-conflicts-after-successful-merge/33226122#33226122)